# Gem install bundler && bundle install error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to install gems using the following:

```
gem install bundler && bundle install
```

It starts out fine, but then I get an error on (Installing gherkin):

```
Successfully installed bundler-1.0.10
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for bundler-1.0.10...
Installing RDoc documentation for bundler-1.0.10...
Fetching source index for http://gemcutter.org/
Fetching source index for http://gems.github.com/
Using rake (0.8.7)
Using activesupport (2.3.5)
Using rack (1.0.1)
Using actionpack (2.3.5)
Using actionmailer (2.3.5)
Using activerecord (2.3.5)
Using activeresource (2.3.5)
Using authlogic (2.1.6)
Using builder (2.1.2)
Using haml (3.0.17)
Using compass (0.8.17)
Using crack (0.1.8)
Using diff-lcs (1.1.2)
Using trollop (1.16.2)

Installing gherkin (2.1.5) with native extensions /ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/installer.rb:482:in `build_extensions': ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension. (Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError)

/ruby/bin/ruby extconf.rb

checking for main() in -lc... no

creating Makefile

make

sh: make: command not found

Gem files will remain installed in /ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/gherkin-2.1.5 for inspection.
Results logged to /ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/gherkin-2.1.5/ext/gherkin_lexer_ar/gem_make.out
/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/installer.rb:445:in `each'
/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/installer.rb:445:in `build_extensions'
/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/installer.rb:197:in `install'
/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/source.rb:96:in `install'
/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/installer.rb:55:in `run'
/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:12:in `each'
/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:12:in `each'
/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/installer.rb:44:in `run'
/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/installer.rb:8:in `install'
/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/cli.rb:226:in `install'
/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:22:in `send'
/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:22:in `run'
/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:118:in `invoke_task'
/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:246:in `dispatch'
/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:389:in `start'
/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.10/bin/bundle:13
/ruby/bin/bundle:19:in `load'
/ruby/bin/bundle:19
```

Comment: are you using mac osx?  If so, I'll bet this is because you don't have the developer tools (and thus gcc) installed.

Comment: on which os are you? You need to install the native `make` or `C development tools`

Comment: @Groovetrain, @Augusto: Yes, I am on Mac OS X 10.6.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welp, I'd say just throw in your OSX cd and install the developer tools.  Then run `gem install bundler` again and see if it works!

Answer (score 5):

```
$ sudo ln -s /bin/mkdir /opt/local/bin/gmkdir
$ sudo ln -s /usr/bin/install /opt/local/bin/ginstall
```

Running these commands seemed to do the trick for me. I ran into this problem when I switched from macports to homebrew.

Answer (score 1):

As @groovetrain and @Augusto have said, you need to install Apple's Developer Tools. These can be found on the OS install disk, or downloaded from the [Apple Developer Connection](https://connect.apple.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Make is not installed, or has been uninstalled. This often happens if you do an OS upgrade, eg from Lion to Mountain lion.

Download the latest command line tools from here:

https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action - approx 100Mb

At a terminal type:

```
make
```

You should have no errors. latest Presto!